# Placing icons inside form fields depending on if inputs are correct

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, icons

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assignment 2 - Website Building</title>
    <style>
        body {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        #login-container {
            width: 460px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }


        form label,
        form input {
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        form input {
            padding: 8px;
        }

        form label {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        form div {
            margin: 16px 0px;
        }

        .invalid {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }

        .valid {
            border: 2px solid green;
        }

        .error-message {
            color: red;
            margin-top: 8px;
        }

        .success-message {
            color: green;
            margin-top: 8px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dde5f4aaa2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="login-container">

        <form id="login-form">
            <div>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input id="username" type="text">
                <span id="username-error" class="error-message"></span>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-check" style="color: #008d63;"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-exclamation" style="color: #ed0202;"></i>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input id="password" type="password">
                <span id="password-error" class="error-message"></span>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-check" style="color: #008d63;"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-exclamation" style="color: #ed0202;"></i>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>

        <div id="error-messages"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("login-form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

            // Reset previous validation styles
            document.getElementById("username").classList.remove("invalid");
            document.getElementById("password").classList.remove("invalid");
            document.getElementById("username").classList.remove("valid");
            document.getElementById("password").classList.remove("valid");
            document.getElementById("error-messages").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("username-error").textContent = "";
            document.getElementById("password-error").textContent = "";

            // Get input values
            var username = document.getElementById("username").value.trim();
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value.trim();

            var errors = [];

            // Validate username and password
            document.getElementById("username").classList.toggle("invalid", username === "" || username !== "new_user");
            document.getElementById("username").classList.toggle("valid", username === "new_user");
            if (username === "") {
                document.getElementById("username-error").textContent = "Please, enter username";
                errors.push("Username is required.");
            } else if (username !== "new_user") {
                document.getElementById("username-error").textContent = "Please, enter valid username";
                errors.push("Invalid username.");
            }

            document.getElementById("password").classList.toggle("invalid", password === "" || password !== "123456789");
            document.getElementById("password").classList.toggle("valid", password === "123456789");
            if (password === "") {
                document.getElementById("password-error").textContent = "Please, enter password";
                errors.push("password is required.");
            } else if (password !== "123456789") {
                document.getElementById("password-error").textContent = "Please, enter valid password";
                errors.push("Invalid password.");

                // Display error messages
                if (errors.length > 0) {
                    var errorMessageHTML = "<ul class='error-message'>";
                    errors.forEach(function (error) {
                        errorMessageHTML += "<li>" + error + "</li>";
                    });
                    errorMessageHTML += "</ul>";
                    document.getElementById("error-messages").innerHTML = errorMessageHTML;
                } else {
                    // Successful login
                    document.getElementById("username").classList.add("valid");
                    document.getElementById("password").classList.add("valid");
                    document.getElementById("error-messages").innerHTML = "<p class='success-message'>Successful login!</p>";
                }
            }
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

What i need:
So basically i need forms to show checkmark and x icons respectively depending if form's input is correct/incorrect. Those icons need to be in form field on the right side, i managed to find out how to get them in structure but i dont know how to put them inside forms and make them hidden while forms are without input.

What i tried:
tried using positions from css but couldnt manage to get it right

Comment: why not simply use the auto-validation mechanic of the form by using `pattern` and `required`? Don't try to reinvent the wheel with the basic standard functions that already exist.

Comment: You should probably put the input field and its two `i` elements into a common inline wrapper, so that you can then position the icons absolute, with the wrapper as reference point. Which one of the two `i` elements to show, you can then determine by modifying the class on the wrapper element.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in script file I removed them all. This is your corrected code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assignment 2 - Website Building</title>
    <style>
        body {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        #login-container {
            width: 460px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }


        form label,
        form input {
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        form input {
            padding: 8px;
        }

        form label {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        form div {
            margin: 16px 0px;
        }

        .invalid {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }

        .valid {
            border: 2px solid green;
        }

        .error-message {
            color: red;
            margin-top: 8px;
        }

        .success-message {
            color: green;
            margin-top: 8px;
        }

        .inputField {
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
        }

        .inputField svg {
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            top: 6px;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dde5f4aaa2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="login-container">

        <form id="login-form">
            <div>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <div class="inputField">
                    <input id="username" type="text">
                    <svg id="check1" fill="#000000" width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="check" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><polyline id="primary" points="5 12 10 17 19 8" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(3, 252, 61); stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-width: 2;"></polyline></svg>
                    <svg id="close1" fill="#000000" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="cross" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><line id="primary" x1="19" y1="19" x2="5" y2="5" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(252, 3, 19); stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-width: 2;"></line><line id="primary-2" data-name="primary" x1="19" y1="5" x2="5" y2="19" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(252, 3, 19); stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-width: 2;"></line></svg>
                </div>
                <span id="username-error" class="error-message"></span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <div class="inputField">
                    <input id="password" type="password">
                    <svg id="check2" fill="#000000" width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="check" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><polyline id="primary" points="5 12 10 17 19 8" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(3, 252, 61); stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-width: 2;"></polyline></svg>
                    <svg id="close2" fill="#000000" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="cross" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><line id="primary" x1="19" y1="19" x2="5" y2="5" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(252, 3, 19); stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-width: 2;"></line><line id="primary-2" data-name="primary" x1="19" y1="5" x2="5" y2="19" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(252, 3, 19); stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-width: 2;"></line></svg>
                </div>
                <span id="password-error" class="error-message"></span>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>

        <div id="error-messages"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("check1").classList.add("hide");
        document.getElementById("check2").classList.add("hide");
        document.getElementById("close1").classList.add("hide");
        document.getElementById("close2").classList.add("hide");

        document.getElementById("login-form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

            // Reset previous validation styles
            document.getElementById("username").classList.remove("invalid");
            document.getElementById("password").classList.remove("invalid");
            document.getElementById("username").classList.remove("valid");
            document.getElementById("password").classList.remove("valid");
            document.getElementById("error-messages").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("username-error").textContent = "";
            document.getElementById("password-error").textContent = "";

            // Get input values
            var username = document.getElementById("username").value.trim();
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value.trim();

            var errors = [];

            // Validate username and password
            document.getElementById("username").classList.toggle("invalid", username === "" || username !== "new_user");
            document.getElementById("username").classList.toggle("valid", username === "new_user");

            if (username === "") {
                document.getElementById("username-error").textContent = "Please, enter username";
                errors.push("Username is required.");
            } else if (username !== "new_user") {
                document.getElementById("username-error").textContent = "Please, enter valid username";
                errors.push("Invalid username.");
            }

            if(username === "new_user") {
                document.getElementById("close1").classList.add("hide");
                document.getElementById("check1").classList.remove("hide");
            } else {
                document.getElementById("check1").classList.add("hide");
                document.getElementById("close1").classList.remove("hide");
            }

            document.getElementById("password").classList.toggle("invalid", password === "" || password !== "123456789");
            document.getElementById("password").classList.toggle("valid", password === "123456789");
            if (password === "") {
                document.getElementById("password-error").textContent = "Please, enter password";
                errors.push("password is required.");
            } else if (password !== "123456789") {
                document.getElementById("password-error").textContent = "Please, enter valid password";
                errors.push("Invalid password.");

            } 

            if(password === "123456789") {
                document.getElementById("close2").classList.add("hide");
                document.getElementById("check2").classList.remove("hide");
            } else {
                document.getElementById("check2").classList.add("hide");
                document.getElementById("close2").classList.remove("hide");
            }

            if (errors.length > 0) {
                // Display error messages
                var errorMessageHTML = "<ul class='error-message'>";
                errors.forEach(function (error) {
                    errorMessageHTML += "<li>" + error + "</li>";
                });
                errorMessageHTML += "</ul>";
                document.getElementById("error-messages").innerHTML = errorMessageHTML;
            } else {
                // Successful login
                document.getElementById("username").classList.add("valid");
                document.getElementById("password").classList.add("valid"); 
                document.getElementById("error-messages").innerHTML = "<p class='success-message'>Successful login!</p>";
            }
        })
    </script>

</body>
```

Have made changes in CSS, Html and Script.

***HTML changes***

I have problems with fonts in html so I have used svg you can use font if you are good with fonts there is no problem.
I have wrapped input field and svg (check icon and close icon) all in a div with class inputField.
In all four svg ( 2 for username and 2 for password ) have used uniqueIds which will be usefull in script code.

***CSS changes***

For inputField have given flex and position relative.
For svg have given absolute and give top and right according to your liking.
Hide to initially hide the svgs as you asked.

***Script changes***

Initially have added hide class to all four svgs so they are hidden.
Then in if condition I am checking whether user has entered correct pass and username if they have then add hide class to close svg and remove hide class from check svg otherwise just do opposite.
Also the last if checking whether errorList if empty or not you have put inside password that should be out.